# get ko.observable value using Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I created a login model,

```
define(["knockout", "text!./login.html"], function (ko, loginTemplate) {
function loginViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.email = ko.observable("");
    self.pass = ko.observable();
    self.newEmail = "";
    self.newPass = "";
    self.email.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        self.newEmail = newValue;
    });
    self.pass.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        self.newPass = newValue;
    });
    self.login = function(){
        alert(self.newEmail);
        alert(self.newPass);
    }
    return self;
}
return { viewModel:loginViewModel, template: loginTemplate };
});
```

I want to get the value of email and password inputs. The code above is working but I used .subscribe function. Is there any other way to get value of email and password?

Comment: *"Is there any other way to get value of email and password?"* — You mean, like, `self.email()` and `self.pass()`? (I believe you need to go though the basic knockout tutorial again.)

Comment: I forgot it. Thanks.